# How to not overwritten the data in input/output in ADA programming

Tags: ada

I need to take the input from user and save the data in a file but data must not be overwritten. The code is running well but data is overwritten. How to correct my code to get desired results?

I could not manage to data to be overwritten. The demand is:"Ask the user to input name, id and CGPA one by one, and then write it in the file. Existing data must not be ". I also have tried the new generated file data to be stored in another file but getting the same result.

```
with Ada.Command_Line, Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Command_Line, Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Main is
   -- Initializing
   Read_From     : constant String := "inputFile.txt";
   Write_To      : constant String := "studentData.txt";
   name          : String (1 .. 13);
   studentID     : String (1 .. 11);
   cgpa          : String (1 .. 4);
   Input, Output : File_Type;
begin
   -- taking inputs
   Put_Line ("My Student ID Is *******bc150400162*******");
   Put_Line ("Enter the details for first student.");
   Put_Line ("Please enter your name:");
   Get (name);
   Put_Line ("Please enter your Student ID:");
   Get (studentID);
   Put_Line ("Please enter your CGPA:");
   Get (cgpa);
   -- opening file
   begin
      Open (File => Input, Mode => In_File, Name => Read_From);
   exception
      when others =>
         Put_Line
           (Standard_Error,
            "Can not open the file '" & Read_From & "'. Does it exist?");
         Set_Exit_Status (Failure);
         return;
   end;
   -- Creating new file file

   begin
      Create (File => Output, Mode => Out_File, Name => Write_To);
   exception
      when others =>
         Put_Line
           (Standard_Error, "Can not create a file named '" & Write_To & "'.");
         Set_Exit_Status (Failure);
         return;
   end;
   -- Here is the loop.............................................
   ------------------
   loop
      declare
         Line : String := Get_Line (Input);
      begin
         Put_Line (Output, Line);
         Put_Line (Output, "The Student details are: ");
         Put_Line (Output, name);
         Put_Line (Output, studentID);
         Put_Line (Output, cgpa);
      end;
   end loop;
exception
   when End_Error =>
      if Is_Open (Input) then
         Close (Input);
      end if;
      if Is_Open (Output) then
         Close (Output);
      end if;
end Main;
```

Comment: No idea how you say it in Ada, but it seems to me you need to figure out the way to say "open file for writing, appending to end if file exists".  Most file systems have such a thing. and most I/O libraries allow you to express it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to try to open the file in append mode, and if that fails create it (again, in append mode). If creating the file fails, you have a different problem (e.g. illegal name? no permissions? file system is read-only? file system is full? none of these addressable in your program!)

Note, open first, create if open fails; the other way round, the file may be reset, which is exactly what you don’t want.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar.Formatting;
with Ada.IO_Exceptions;
procedure Appending is
   Output : Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;
   Name : constant String := "appending.dat";
begin
```

We need a block here, so the exception can be caught here.

```ada
   begin
```

Try to open the file ...

```ada
      Ada.Text_IO.Open (File => Output,
                        Name => Name,
                        Mode => Ada.Text_IO.Append_File);
```

`Open` succeeded!

```ada
   exception
      when Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error =>
```

`Open` failed because the name didn’t represent an openable file. Try to create it ...

```ada
         Ada.Text_IO.Create (File => Output,
                             Name => Name,
                             Mode => Ada.Text_IO.Append_File);
```

The file `Output` is now open, in append mode.
(At first glance, you might wonder what the point of opening a file that must have been empty in append mode is. Normally, of course, it might as well have been opened in standard out mode; the only difference would be if for some reason you had to use the modeless [`Reset`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-1.html#p11). In that case, if the file was created in append mode it would remain in append mode, so any previous updates wouldn’t be lost.)

```ada
   end;
```

Write something 'unique' to it, so we can tell it worked ...

```ada
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
     (File => Output,
      Item => Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Image (Ada.Calendar.Clock));
```

... and we’re done. Could leave the OS to close the file for us on exit, but let’s be sure.

```ada
   Ada.Text_IO.Close (File => Output);
end Appending;
```